# Regex matching too much of a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match on multiple strings using `preg_match` with the following regex:

`#^/test/(.+?)(\/.+^/?)?$#`

The results on the following strings are as follows

Match (should match)

```
preg_match('#^/test/(.+?)(\/.+?)?$#', '/test/segment'); // true
preg_match('#^/test/(.+?)(\/.+?)?$#', '/test/segment/another-segment'); // true
```

No Match (shouldn't match)

```
preg_match('#^/test/(.+?)(\/.+?)?$#', '/test'); // false
```

Match (shouldn't match)

```
preg_match('#^/test/(.+?)(\/.+?)?$#', '/test/segment/another-segment/yet-another/segment'); // true
```

Can anybody tell me how to make the last one fail? Breaking the regex down, essentially it should match a literal `/test` followed by a required `/something` with an optional `/something` but stop at any next occurrence of `/something`.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `.` by `[^\/]`, otherwise the dots will match some slashes.

Comment: which dot? the second one?

Comment: You can replace both, as Neither nor dot should match slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pattern:

```
preg_match('~^/test(?>/[^/]++){1,2}+$~', $yourstring)
```